# Given two absolute paths, how can I express one of the paths relative to the other?

Tags: path, rust

I think this should be quite doable, given that there is a nice function [`canonicalize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html) which normalizes paths (so I can start by normalizing my two input paths) and `Path` and `PathBuf` give us a way of iterating over the parts of paths through [`components`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.components). I imagine something could be worked out here to factor out a common prefix, then prepend as many `..` components as remain in the anchor path to what remains of the initial input path.

My problem seems to be pretty common:

1. [How to find relative path given two absolute paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055511/how-to-find-relative-path-given-two-absolute-paths)
2. [Find a path in Windows relative to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654659/find-a-path-in-windows-relative-to-another)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This now exists as the [`pathdiff`](https://docs.rs/pathdiff/0.1.0/pathdiff/) crate, using the code from [kennytm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343127/1198729)

You can use it as:

```
extern crate pathdiff;

pathdiff::diff_paths(path, base);
```

where `base` is where the relative path should be applied to obtain `path`

Answer (score 27):

If one path is a base of another, you could use [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix), but it won't calculate the `../` for you (instead returns an Err):

```
use std::path::*;
let base = Path::new("/foo/bar");
let child_a = Path::new("/foo/bar/a");
let child_b = Path::new("/foo/bar/b");
println!("{:?}", child_a.strip_prefix(base));     // Ok("a")
println!("{:?}", child_a.strip_prefix(child_b));  // Err(StripPrefixError(()))
```

The previous incarnation of `strip_prefix` was `path_relative_from` which used to add `../`, but [this behavior was dropped due to symlinks](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23284#issuecomment-85118123):

> 1. The current behavior where joining the result onto the first path unambiguously refers to the same thing the second path does, even if there's symlinks (which basically means `base` needs to be a prefix of `self`)
> 2. The old behavior where the result can start with `../` components. Symlinks mean traversing the `base` path and then traversing the returned relative path may not put you in the same directory that traversing the `self` path does. But this operation is useful when either you're working with a path-based system that doesn't care about symlinks, or you've already resolved symlinks in the paths you're working with.

If you need the `../` behavior, you could copy the implementation from [librustc_back](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e1d0de82cc40b666b88d4a6d2c9dcbc81d7ed27f/src/librustc_back/rpath.rs#L116-L158) (the compiler backend). I didn't find any packages on crates.io providing this yet.

```
// This routine is adapted from the *old* Path's `path_relative_from`
// function, which works differently from the new `relative_from` function.
// In particular, this handles the case on unix where both paths are
// absolute but with only the root as the common directory.
fn path_relative_from(path: &Path, base: &Path) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    use std::path::Component;

    if path.is_absolute() != base.is_absolute() {
        if path.is_absolute() {
            Some(PathBuf::from(path))
        } else {
            None
        }
    } else {
        let mut ita = path.components();
        let mut itb = base.components();
        let mut comps: Vec<Component> = vec![];
        loop {
            match (ita.next(), itb.next()) {
                (None, None) => break,
                (Some(a), None) => {
                    comps.push(a);
                    comps.extend(ita.by_ref());
                    break;
                }
                (None, _) => comps.push(Component::ParentDir),
                (Some(a), Some(b)) if comps.is_empty() && a == b => (),
                (Some(a), Some(b)) if b == Component::CurDir => comps.push(a),
                (Some(_), Some(b)) if b == Component::ParentDir => return None,
                (Some(a), Some(_)) => {
                    comps.push(Component::ParentDir);
                    for _ in itb {
                        comps.push(Component::ParentDir);
                    }
                    comps.push(a);
                    comps.extend(ita.by_ref());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Some(comps.iter().map(|c| c.as_os_str()).collect())
    }
}
```

Comment: This has now been extracted into the pathdiff crate https://docs.rs/pathdiff/0.1.0/pathdiff/

Comment: @Manishearth Thanks. Perhaps you should post that as an answer :D